# AS3 tracing datagrid content

Tags: actionscript-3, csv

I cant seem to work out to trace the content of a data grid i have populated with info;
Once I can work out how to trace it or each row i would push it into a new array for exporting.

so for example: i have a datagrid instanceNamed(info) //populated from a CVS file; text file//

containing 150 rows and 15 columns. I would simply like to trace this in the output window .From then i will work out how to write to disk.

i have been searching around but cant seem to find a solution to this problem.

thank you

Comment: why not to trace directly the content of the cvs file? your question is a little confusing

Comment: i can do that but its pointless as im changing the values  in the dataGrid, the original imported cvs file doesnt get effected from the new changes, this is for a pc/xbox game update player stats

Comment: Its CSV, not CVS. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values and is a file format. CVS stands for Concurrent Versions System and is a client-server based version control system.

Comment: Its CSV, not CVS. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values , doesnt matter what its called the point was to trace what ever data from a data grid , not to correct the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out how to trace a single cell or an entire DataGrid, Below is an example:

```
        function trace_dataGrid(){
        for (var k:Number = 0; k < DataGrid.length - 1; k++) {
        var info += DataGrid.getItemAt(k).Team_name + "," + 
               DataGrid.getItemAt(k).Player_name+"\r\n";
               trace(info);
               }
        }
```

OutPut
Australia Footy,Bob
Sydney Soccer,David
Australia Cricket,Jim

[image: AS3 Data Grid Example ,Tracing cell or row values]

RunThrough:
 First creat a loop counter "k" which is checking the Data Grid "length"
"get item AT" will check the first location,matching to the variable in the DataGrid 
"TeamName" / " PlayerName is the next reference. After this has done it will repeat this "k++"  Same structure until the condition is met(counter == datagrids Length-1) for better understanding the best bet would be how to structure Arrays,tuts ect.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial: [Using the Flex Automation API with Fluint](http://code.google.com/p/fluint/wiki/FluintAndAutomationAPI)

What you need is implemented in the `getValuesFromGrid()`-method. Check how the `DataGridTabularData` is used.

Comment: my bad its a no-go but i should  of mention that im using cs5 flash /as3